# Plugin doesnt appear among controller types

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the bottom of my .cpp file I have

```
// make the controller available to the library loader
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(hiqp::ROSKinematicsController, controller_interface::ControllerBase)
```

but when I run

```
rosservice call /controller_manager/list_controller_types
```

the ROSKinematicsController does not appear.

Shall this be sufficient for loading a controller as a plugin, or have I forgotten something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240887/plugin-doesnt-appear-among-controller-types/) by [neckutrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/27626/neckutrek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi neckutrek,

Did you also provide a [Plugin File Description](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.The_Plugin_Description_File) and [register it with the ROS package system](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.Registering_Plugin_with_ROS_Package_System)?

If you carefully follow all the steps as described on the [pluginlib wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib), it should work.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0